# Missing Numbers in Roulette, Dice, and Other Gambling Devices

Tags: combinatorics

Case 1:  I roll a die N times.   What is the probability that one of the 6 numbers never comes up?  The probability that K of the 6 numbers never comes up?

Case 2:  Same idea, but with a Las Vegas roulette wheel (38 possible outcomes).   What is probability that, after N rolls, there are K numbers that have not come up?

I am looking for a combinatoric explanation; back it up with enumeration or monte carlo simulation to check your work, if you like.   Spreadsheets are good for this.

Thanks, for help.  This problem has been bugging me for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y$ be the number of distinct faces that
occur in $n$ throws of an $r$-sided die.
Then $$\mathbb{P}(Y=k)={\displaystyle{r\choose k}\,  {n\brace k} \, k!\over { r^n}}.$$
Here ${n\brace k}$ refers to a Stirling number of the second kind.

This is the probability that there are exactly $n-k$ missing faces.

---

**Explanation:** The probability is a ratio, where the denominator is the number $r^n$ of 
all possible outcomes  and the numerator is the number of those outcomes with exactly
$k$ distinct values occurring.

The factor $r\choose k$ comes from selecting which $k$ values of the possible $r$ will occur.

The factor ${n\brace  k}$ counts the number of ways of dividing the $n$ indices into 
$k$ non-empty sets.

Finally, the factor $k!$ is the number of ways to assign the $k$ values to the $k$ 
non-empty sets.

---

**Example:** Let's take $r=6$, $n=9$, and $k=4$. In other words, we throw an 
ordinary die 9 times and ask for the chance that we observe exactly four distinct values.
Here is an example of a favorable outcome: $(1,3,3,1,4,6,3,3,4)$.

In the first step there are ${6\choose 4}=15$ ways to select the four values;
we happened to take $\{1,3,4,6\}$.

In the second step, there are ${9\brace 4}=7770$ ways to divide the nine indices 
into 4 non-empty sets; we happened to get $\left\{\{1,4\}, \{2,3,7,8\},\{5,9\},\{6\}\right\}$.

In the third step, there are $4!=24$ ways to assign the four values to these four 
sets of indices; we happened to choose $1\mapsto \{1,4\}$, $3\mapsto \{2,3,7,8\},
6\mapsto \{6\},$ and $4\mapsto \{5,9\}$. So a "$1$" goes in positions 1,4, a "$3$" goes 
in  positions 2,3,7,8, a "$6$" goes in position 6, and a "$4$" goes into positions 
5,9. This results in the outcome $(1,3,3,1,4,6,3,3,4)$.

The total number of ways to fulfill these three tasks is $15\times 7770\times 24=2797200$, so there are over two million favorable outcomes. The probability is 
therefore $$\mathbb{P}(Y=4)={2797200\over 10077696}\approx .277563.$$

Comment: Thank you for this, thank you for educating me.

Answer (score 1):

The Probability P that you miss one number in one round is $\frac{AllPossibilities-1}{AllPossibilities}$. If you have K missing numbers, you get $\frac{AllPossibilities-K}{AllPossibilities}$. If you have N rounds, the probabilities multiply: 
$\Big(\frac{AllPossibilities-K}{AllPossibilities}\Big)^N$. Therefore it's easy to apply to your cases:

**Case 1**

$$P_{K=1}=\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)^N$$
$$P_{K}=\Big(\frac{6-K}{6}\Big)^N$$

**Case 2**
$$P_{K=1}=\Big(\frac{37}{38}\Big)^N$$
$$P_{K}=\Big(\frac{38-K}{38}\Big)^N$$

Comment: Following Polya's suggestion to start simple, consider a three sided die that is rolled three times.  There are 27 possible results, of which 6 have no missing number, 18 have one missing number, and 3 have two missing numbers.  The above answer is correct only if the missing outcome is specfied before the game.  It looks like some nasty inclusion-exclusion calculations are headed our way.

Comment: I enumerated the three-sided die for the case of 3 rolls and for the case of 4 rolls.   The above comment was found to be correct for 3 rolls.   For the case of four rolls, where the results were 4-tuples of integers 1,2, and 3, the sample space has 81 elements.  36 of those had no missing numbers, 42 had exactly one missing number and 3 had exactly two missing numbers (these were 1111, 2222, and 3333).  More enumeration results later.  These are important because they can serve as a sanity check for a combinatorial argument.

Comment: NocoDean's answer is correct only if I specify the missing numbers before doing the experiment.   But, if I don't, things get more complex.   Some application of inclusion-exclusion is required.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I cracked the problem and worked it out for a six-sided die.   Combinatorial answers are in close agreement with Monte Carlo (a day of running under excel on an old snailbook).   The trick was to ask the opposite question and work backwards.

Original question: probability that one number does not occur in N rolls of the die.
Reverse question: probability that exactly 5 numbers occur in N rolls of the die.   This is a bit nasty, but we can ask the probability that only 1 number occurs in N rolls of the die.   I picked N = 12, but the solution for other values of N will be obvious.

For N = 12, P1 = 6C1 * (1/6)^12

For the probability that exactly two of the faces appear in 12 rolls, an approximate answer would be 6C2 * (2/6)^12, but alas this includes elements of P1 counted 5C1 times.   This leads to

P2 = 6C2 * (2/6)^12 - 5C1 * P1

Next, an estimate that exactly three faces appear is 6C3 *(3/6)^12, but this counts events in P2 4C1 times and events in P1 5C2 times, so

P3 = 6C3*(3/6)^12 - 4C1*P2 - 5C2*P1.

Similarly,

P4 = 6C4*(4/6)^12 - 3C1*P3 - 4C2*P2 - 5C3*P1

P5 = 6C5*(5/5)^12 - 2C1*P4 - 3C2*P3 - 4C3*P2 - 5C4*P1     This is the one we wanted, five faces appear, one face does not appear in 12 rolls of the die.

As a sanity check, 
P6 = 6C6*(6/6)^12 - 1C1*P5 - 2C2*P4 - 3C3*P3 - 4C4*P2 - 5C5*P1

= 1 - P5 - P4 - P3 - P2 - P1.

Approximate numerical values,

P1:   2.8E-9

P2:   2.82E-5

P3:   0.00048

P4:   0.10113

P5:   0.45626

P6:   0.43782   (my apologies for rounding errors)

Intuitively, the most likely distribution would be for each die face to appear twice in 12 throws.   The probability of this, however is only about 0.03.

Thanks for all the help you gave me on this one.   It bugged me for a 3 weeks; my wife (Master's in math) totally gave up on it after arguing a wrong answer!